# Android images increase APK size

Tags: android, image

I am developing an android app which has many icons and full screen size images. Due to using different densities of  icons and images app size increased. Now i am using vector drawable for icons. So, icons size problem is gone. I read vector drawables are not suitable for full screen images, So, what i do for full screen images for reduce the apk size.

Comment: Live with it, mostly.  You can download the images from the web instead, but then you have to pay to host them.

Comment: You can try [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html) on API 14+

Comment: well you can put your images to a free hosting site and just download it when you open your app. note that this will make your internet usage bigger

Comment: Use only one image for the biggest size and scale it down for other sizes

Comment: Perhaps minify your application